# Why am I getting this error when overriding an inherited method?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here's my parent class:

```
    public abstract class BaseFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

        public abstract void GetFileInformation();
        public abstract void GetThumbnail();

    }
```

And here's the class that's inheriting it:

```
    public class Picture:BaseFile
    {
        public override void  GetFileInformation(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (fileInformation.Exists)
            {
                Name = fileInformation.Name;
                FileType = fileInformation.Extension;
                Size = fileInformation.Length;
                CreationDate = fileInformation.CreationTime;
                ModificationDate = fileInformation.LastWriteTime;
            }
        }

        public override void GetThumbnail()
        {

        }
    }
```

I thought when a method was overridden, I could do what I wanted with it. Any help please? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change the signature of an overridden method.  (Except for covariant return types)

In your code, what would you expect to happen if I run the following:

```
BaseFile file = new Picture();
file.GetFileInformation();  //Look ma, no parameters!
```

What would the `filePath` parameter be?

You should change the parameters of the base and derived methods to be identical.

Comment: By signature you mean the string filePath I'm giving the GetFileInformation in my picture class? What alternative is there?

Comment: public abstract void GetFileInformation();
should be public abstract void GetFileInformation(string filePath);

Comment: You need to have the same parameters in both classes.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The alternative is to define a new method rather than overriding one, or to change the abstract method's signature so that it has appropriate parameters for what you want it to be used for.

Comment: What if I want Picture.cs to have a string filePath given to the GetFileInformation(), but in another child class, let's call it, Video.cs I don't want to pass anything to the same method; just call GetFileInformation()?

Comment: That would have to be 2 different methods.

Comment: That would not make sense; see my code example.  You should probably  create independent methods and not have an `abstract` method in the base class.

Comment: Something clicked and I now understand why it wouldn't make sense. Thanks a bunch guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a parameter in the derived class that's not declared in the parent class. (`string filepath` in the `getFileInformation` method)